# Java - Scanner execute only the Int and "skip" the Strings data types when i input String data before the Int ones

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

While I'm working with `java.util.Scanner`, I tried to use integers and `String`s at data input.

The problem that I faced is, when I input an Int data before a String one, the console skip the String data and go immediately to the next Int one.

Here is my simple problem where the problem is happening :

```
package justForTest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmptySpaceWorkshop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("- Enter your Name : ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("- Enter your IC number : ");
        int icNumber = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("- Enter your Place of birth : ");
        String placeOfBirth = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("- Enter your Age : ");
        int age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("There once was a wonderful person named " + name+ ", His IC number is " + icNumber );

        System.out.println(". He/She is " + age + " years old. She/He was born at " + placeOfBirth );

    }

}
```

And here is my output:

```
- Enter your Name : Ali HISOKA
- Enter your IC number : 123456
- Enter your Place of birth : - Enter your Age :
```

I tried a lot to fix this problem. The only solution I could came up with is using `input.next();` instead of `input.nextLine();` . However, this solution is USELESS for me because as you guys know, when using `input.next();` we can only type One Single Word, unlike `input.nextLine();` we can type a lot of words which is the thing that I'm looking for. Also I DO NOT want to re-sort (re-arrange) my input and type the Strings data first, then following by the Int data to solve my problem. I want my data to be at the same sort as you seen above in my simple program ( Enter Name, Enter IC Number, Enter Place of Birth, then Enter age). So can I solve this problem ?

I searched a lot on the internet for someone got a problem as mine, but I couldn't find a question and solution for a problem looks exactly like mine.

I already know the reason and the explanation of my problem which is explained by

> Joshua
>
> "The reason for the error is that the nextInt only pulls the integer,
>   not the newline. If you add a in.nextLine() before your for loop, it
>   will eat the empty new line and allow you to enter 3 names."

but still it's not helpful for solving my problem.

Comment: Your "output" seem to be your input...? Your quoted answer is correct: Just add a call to input.nextLine() without assigning the result directly after your call to nextInt().

Comment: @AliHISOKA I cannot reproduce your problem. Looking at your output, your first entry is `Ali HISOKA` which is consumed by `nextLine()` and assigned to `String name`. Your second entry is `123456` which is consumed by `nextInt()` and assigned to `int icNumber`. Everything is fine so far and it doesn't produce the output you have showed.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard , What do you mean of "Just add a call to input.nextLine() without assigning the result directly after your call to nextInt()." .. Can you please explain more and in details. Thanks

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak, Sorry i made a mistake in my program codes , i meant to make my placeOfBirth String as 'input.nextLine();'  and show my problem. So yeah ^^" .. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see it appears that the `readLine()` is just consuming the newline left after the int was taken from the buffer. A better way to fix this is to use `nextLine()` to get a string value and convert it:

```
int icNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: WooW AWESOME !!! very Nice and Useful way .. It works perfectly! .. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah Sure, There you go :) .. i also would appreciate your vote up to my question as it rises up my reputation, so i can use the vote up ;)

Comment: @AliHISOKA People will up-vote your question if they will like it. Generally asking for up-votes gets opposite results so try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Think of your input as a single string:

`"Ali HISOKA\n123456\nPLACE\n99"`

- `next()` consumes the first word, up to first white space - e.g. `" "` or `"\n"`
- `nextLine()` consumes the first word, up to first new line character
- `nextInt()` consumes first word, as `next()`, and parses it to int - it will throw an exception if the word cannot be parsed.

Now, let's have a look what your calls are consuming:

1. `nextLine()` will return `"Ali HISOKA"`, the remaining string is `"123456\nPLACE\n99"`
2. `nextInt()` will return int `123456`, the remaining string is `"\nPLACE\n99"`
3. `nextLine()` will return empty string `""`, the remaining string is `"PLACE\n99"`
4. `nextInt()` will throw an exception, because it will try to parse `"PLACE"` to int.

The trick is in step 2 - although `nextInt()` consumes all white spaces between words, it however does not consume new line character, hence `nextLine()` in step 3 reads empty string because `"\n"` is first character in the remaining string.

There are two solutions:

1. Instead of using `nextInt()` you can read and parse the whole line `Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine())`. If the line contains a few words, e.g. `"1234 abc"` it will throw the exception.
2. Call `input.nextLine()` after calling `nextInt()`, so it consumes the remaining string up to first new line character. For input `"1234 abc"` it will ignore everything after the number.

I would recommend the first solution, because when you are asked for the number and you answer "123 abc", it is not a valid answer. In such case the user should be told that the input is invalid, instead of taking only a valid part from that answer - user would have no clue that part of his answer was ignored.

Comment: WooW That's very detailed answer .. Thank you so much .. Now i understand my problem perfectly and its solution perfectly as well :) .. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing because the code you posted does not show your original problem, but the situation after putting in a workaround.

You need to skip the newline after `nextInt()`

```
    System.out.print("- Enter your IC number : ");
    int icNumber = input.nextInt();
    input.skip("\\n");
```

Without the skip, `input.newLine` (for the place of birth) will match the newline after the entered IC number and you will be prompted for the age.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my program codes , i meant to make my placeOfBirth String as 'input.nextLine();' and show my problem .. Lemme try the 'input.newLine' out

Comment: I tried using the 'input.skip("\\n); and It skip the entire text after the Place Of Birth .. here is my new input and output : Input `System.out.print("- Enter your Name : ");
  String name = input.nextLine();
  
  System.out.print("- Enter your IC number : ");
  int icNumber = input.nextInt();
  
  
  System.out.print("- Enter your Place of birth : ");
  String placeOfBirth = input.nextLine();
  input.skip("//n");
  
  System.out.print("- Enter your Age : ");
  int age = input.nextInt();`

Comment: and here is the out put - Enter your Name : `Ali HISOKA                       
- Enter your IC number : 23232                                       
- Enter your Place of birth : dfdf dfdfdf `                            and Nothing shown after entering the place of birth

Comment: You put the skip in the wrong place.  It should be after all the options which do not consume the newline.

Comment: Here is my output When i put the `input.skip("\\n")` after `int icNumber = input.nextLine();` ::  - Enter your Name : Ali HISOKA                                         
- Enter your IC number : 23232  ... That All what i got in the Console. So the question here, why `input.skip` skips everything after the icNumber?

Comment: Read my answer - there is a `skip` after a `nextInt` not a `nextLine`.  With a `skip` after a `nextLine`, the console is waiting for you to enter another newline.

Comment: [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z72xztc3av4vko/vhh.PNG?dl=0)    .... Here you go : I got the same result after changing nextLine of icNumber to nextInt

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code at my machine without making any changes and Its working fine.Below is my output.

- Enter your Name : yash
- Enter your IC number : 12
- Enter your Place of birth : alg
- Enter your Age : 25
  There once was a wonderful person named yash, His IC number is 12
  . He/She is 25 years old. She/He was born at alg

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my codes, i suppose to assign placeOfBirth as 'input.nextLine();' to show my problem .. So now if you assign placeOfBirth as nextLine , you will see the problem